# Ruby Truncate Words + Long Text

Tags: ruby, regex, truncation

I have the following function which accepts text and a word count and if the number of words in the text exceeded the word-count it gets truncated with an ellipsis.

```
#Truncate the passed text. Used for headlines and such
  def snippet(thought, wordcount)
    thought.split[0..(wordcount-1)].join(" ") + (thought.split.size > wordcount ? "..." : "")
  end
```

However what this function doesn't take into account is extremely long words, for instance...

> "Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   world!"

I was wondering if there's a better way to approach what I'm trying to do so it takes both word count and text size into consideration in an efficient way.

Comment: What problems occur when using long words?
Apparently, it **should** work, as you are only accounting number of words, not their lengths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a Rails project?

Why not use the following helper:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :length => 17)
```

If not, just reuse the code.

Comment: Truncate is nice. If you just want the code for the truncate method, you can find it here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ac4c5e97226fd70510ed49872f0ae41ba0d71c52/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb#L38

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a two step process:

1. Truncate the string to a max length (no need for regex for this)
2. Using regex, find a max words quantity from the truncated string.

---

Edit:

Another approach is to split the string into words, loop through the array adding up
the lengths. When you find the overrun, `join 0 .. index` just before the overrun.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:*** regex `^(\s*.+?\b){5}` will match first 5 "words"

Answer (score 0):

The logic for checking both word and char limits becomes too convoluted to clearly express as one expression.  I would suggest something like this:

```
def snippet str, max_words, max_chars, omission='...'
  max_chars = 1+omision.size if max_chars <= omission.size # need at least one char plus ellipses
  words = str.split
  omit = words.size > max_words || str.length > max_chars ? omission : ''
  snip = words[0...max_words].join ' '
  snip = snip[0...(max_chars-3)] if snip.length > max_chars
  snip + omit
end
```

As other have pointed out Rails String#truncate offers almost the functionality you want (truncate to fit in length at a natural boundary), but it doesn't let you independently state max char length and word count.

Answer (score 0):

**First 20 characters**:

```
>> "hello world this is the world".gsub(/.+/) { |m| m[0..20] + (m.size > 20 ? '...' : '') }
=> "hello world this is t..."
```

**First 5 words**:

```
>> "hello world this is the world".gsub(/.+/) { |m| m.split[0..5].join(' ') + (m.split.size > 5 ? '...' : '') }
=> "hello world this is the world..."
```